# How do I set a DOM element's text in Reason?

Tags: javascript, dom, reason

I'm currently learning Reason. Here's what I've written so far:

```
[@bs.val] external document: Dom.document = "document";
[@bs.send]
external get_element_by_id: (Dom.document, string) => Js.nullable(Dom.node) =
  "getElementById";

let our_node =
  Js.Nullable.toOption(get_element_by_id(document, "do_something"));

let d = Js.Date.make();
switch (our_node) {
| None => Js.log("can't find the output element")
| Some(nnode) => nnode.textContent = Js.Date.toString(d)
};
```

I want to set a DOM node's text to current date. However, I've received an error: `The record field textContent can't be found`. Looking into node_modules/bs-platform/lib/ocaml/dom.ml, I see that, indeed, there isn't a `textContent` field in `Dom.node` or `Dom.htmlElement` or the like. How do I set the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution by doing a bit of digging in [bs-webapi](https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-webapi-incubator/blob/master/src/Webapi/Webapi__Dom/Webapi__Dom__Element.re) code.

Apparently you just need to add a `bs-set` directive:

```
[@bs.set] external setTextContent: (Dom.htmlElement, string) => unit = "textContent";
```

It's explained more thoroughly in ["Property access" docs for BuckleScript.](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/property-access#static-property-access)